# Ionic 3 Changing ion card header padding is not overriding the existing one

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I am trying to override existing sass styling of `ion-card`, by changing the headers padding to something that fit my app.

I did the following:

```
ion-card-header{
  .card-header-md{
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 16px !important;
    padding-top: 16px !important;
    padding-bottom: 16px !important;
  }
}
```

But nothing changed. I tried to add a background color to check it is getting the styling:

```
ion-card-header{
  color: red;
  .card-header-md{
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 16px !important;
    padding-top: 16px !important;
    padding-bottom: 16px !important;
  }
}
```

And the color changed to red. **But the `card-header-md` is not changing**. I need to change it on iOS and Android.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-z5ajr3) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `card-header-md` class is at the same level as the `ion-card-header` class. So this should work:

```
ion-card-header {
  &.card-header-md {
    padding-right: 20px
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
  }
}
```

I've removed the `!important` because I think you don't actually need them (just tried in a **[new stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7rr93h)** and it's working fine without them).